# Create Multiple Rows in Tab Control

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I know that the default behavior of TabControl is to wrap the tabs but that is not happening in my case. I think that is because of the Grid within which the TabControl is placed.

I have a Tab Control. This is placed inside a Stack Panel. This has enough space for 3 tabs. Now i want to add a fourth tab and it is not wrapping. I did some research and found that if we use any Style or ControlTemplate, this will prevent the Tabcontrol from wrapping.

Following is the code for ControlTemplate that i use for the TabControl. I am seeing all the tabs in the same row while i actually want it wrap after 3rd tab. 
Can someone pls tell me how to achieve that.

```
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="700">
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Grid>
              <Border Name="Border" CornerRadius="6,6,0,0" Height="30" Margin="0,0,2,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" >
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="12,2,12,2" />
              </Border>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#BEC39F" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#8A863D" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Grid Height="525">
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <TabPanel Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="1" Margin="0,0,4,-1" IsItemsHost="True" Background="Transparent" />
              <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0, 12, 12, 12">
                <Border.Background>
                  <LinearGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#BEC39F" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                  </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
              </Border>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="150" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="484" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <TabControl Margin="0,0,0,-61" Name="tabControl1" >
      <TabItem Name="tab0" >
        <TabItem.Header>
          Tab0
        </TabItem.Header>
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem Name="tab1">
        <TabItem.Header>
          Tab1
        </TabItem.Header>
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem Header="Tab2" Name="tab2">
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem Header="Tab3" Name="tab3"></TabItem>
    </TabControl>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

if I am understanding your question, you want the tab 3 to wrap and it doesn't. I played with your code and didn't have a problem with TabControl wrapping, what I see is that it does it in a certain way. Basically it won't wrap only one item because it looks funny. Replace TabPanel in your template with wrap panel and you will see what I mean.

Pasting code below that will do that - wrap one item at a time:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid Height="525">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <WrapPanel Margin="0,0,4,-1" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                            <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0, 12, 12, 12">
                                <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#BEC39F" Offset="0" />
                                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Border.Background>
                                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="SelectedContent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>                         
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

if you are hardcoding your tab items you could give your tab3 a certain width and it won't look as weird

```
<TabItem Header="Tab3" Name="tab3"/>
```